# Introduction to linear algebra 4ed by Strang: In $A = QR$, why is $R$'s diagonal entries positive? Can any one see whether my proof is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going to ask a question i have thought about.

In the page 236, the textbook says

> Any $m$ by $n$ matrix $A$ with independent columns can be factored into $QR$.
> The $m$ by $n$ matrix $Q$ has orthonormal columns, and the square matrix $R$
> is upper triangular with positive diagonal.

1. I am not sure about my proof that $R$ has positive diagonal entries.
2. Does it only apply to real matrix case?

Suppose
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2 & a_3
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        \\
        q_1 & q_2 & q_3 \\
        \\
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
        q_1^T a_1 & q_1^T a_2 & q_1^T a_3 \\
        & q_2^T a_2 & q_2^T a_3 \\
        & & q_3^T a_3
    \end{bmatrix}.
$$

For example, let's look at $q_2^T a_2$.
$$
  q_2^T a_2 = \frac{(a_2 - q_1 q_1^T a_2)^T}{\| a_2 - q_1 q_1^T a_2 \|} a_2.
$$
We want to show (WTS)
$$
  (a_2 - q_1 q_1^T a_2)^T a_2 > 0.
$$
That is
$$
  a_2^T a_2 - a_2^T q_1 q_1^T a_2 = a_2^T (I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2.
$$
We can know that $I - q_1 q_1^T$ is a projection matrix. Thus,
\begin{aligned}
  a_2^T (I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2 &= a_2^T (I - q_1 q_1^T)^T (I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2 \\
  &= ((I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2)^T ((I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2) \\
  &= \| (I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2 \|^2 \geq 0.
\end{aligned}
Since $a_2$ is independent of $q_1$, $(I - q_1 q_1^T) a_2$ cannot be zero vector. Thus, the above result shall be strictly larger than zero.

This proof can be generalized easily, so we prove the statement.

Comment: So you only want to go from the statement without "with positive diagonal" to the one with?

Comment: You cannot prove that $R$ has a positive diagonal, because $QR=(-Q)(-R)$. However, $R$ can always be *chosen* to have a positive diagonal, even when $A$ is complex.

Comment: note: the self imposed requirement that $R$ has positive diagonals makes it unique which can be useful in many cases

Comment: @AHusain Ah, I originally thought that the consequence of this decomposition, $A=QR$, is $R$ has positive diagonal entries.

Comment: @user1551 Oh, you mean that $R$ having postive diagonal entries is not the consequence of the decomposition, but our intentional choice, right? But I cannot find where my proof is wrong, it seems that $q_2^T a_2$ is positive.

Comment: @user8675309 Thx! I also noted this in other materials, but did not check the proof on it yet.

Comment: You should have $q_2^Ta_2=\pm\frac{(a_2 - q_1 q_1^T a_2)^T}{\| a_2 - q_1 q_1^T a_2 \|} a_2$, where the sign is not known.